# Sample gradient range in Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to put together a simple shader with Unity' Shader graph. The material should appear white, yellow and blue - and static. However in the sample gradient, it's only displaying yellow. If I change the time input to Sine, the gradients blends through the colours. What is going wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plug an "UV" node in the gradient sampler's "time" input instead of a "Time" node.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to know is that a Gradient goes from 0 to 1.
The 0 is on the left (in white) and the 1 in on the right (in yellow).
I guess that the blue is between approx. 0.25 and 0.3.

On the other hand, you use the Time, which has a constantly evolving value far above 1. Therefore, it is always on the max, meaning plain yellow.

If you use SinTime, the value alternates with a sinusoid between 0 and 1, making the color go from left to right then from right to left.

Additional information: as of today (2019.1.12) it seems that there is a bug in Shader Graph when you use Gradient on a system where the decimal separator is ","
The generated shader is created with a "," instead of "." in functions, messing up the arguments.